# Django EmailMessage send() inserts exclamation marks (! ) throughout email

Tags: django, html-email

I've been batteling with a mysterious bug resulting from the EmailMessage class where the final email that I'm sending myself ends up with "! " inserted throughout the body. Currently, I'm sending emails with the following code:

```
   html_content = render_to_string('layouts/option1.html', request.POST)
   subject = "just a test email"
   from_email = request.user.email
   recipient = [from_email, ]
   msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, to=recipient, headers={
       'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
       'MIME-Version': '1.0'
   })
   msg.content_subtype = "html"
   try:
       msg.send()
       response['success'] = True
       response['html_content'] = html_content
   except:
       pass
```

I've found a similar [thread](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/75331/exclamation-points-at-odd-places-in-php-email) (but for php) that discusses something very similar. Apparently this has to do with the message length. I am in fact sending a rather long html-email but I'm unable to implement the pythonic version of the  solution that mimics what they propose in my link.

**Any help or suggestions on how to prevent the "! " from appearing would be very greatly appreciated!!!**

Thank you,
Fy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here should be the python version of that PHP solution:

```
import textwrap

html_content = render_to_string('layouts/option1.html', request.POST)
encoded_content = '\r\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(html_content.encode('base64'), 76))
subject = "just a test email"
from_email = request.user.email
recipient = [from_email, ]
msg = EmailMessage(subject, encoded_content, from_email, to=recipient, headers={
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',  # why not UTF-8 here?
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'base64',
    'MIME-Version': '1.0'
})
msg.content_subtype = "html"
try:
    msg.send()
    response['success'] = True
    response['html_content'] = html_content
except:
    pass
```

I don't have time to test this whole function but hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the utf-8 encoding. That's what solved it for me in the end!

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Django 1.10 in [this pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6469/files).